# During jama'at prayers, what are you suppose to do when the Imam is say Hamd and Surah?

Tags: salat, jamaat

Are you suppose to just listen the hamd of the Imam? What if you are too far away? Where should your mind be set to? Can you say any dhikr if you can't hear? If so what dhikrs are recommended?

Comment: You mean Surah Fatiha not 'Hamd'?

Comment: You just listen. If you can't hear it and people in front of you can then just copy them so when they do Sajdah etc you do it.

Comment: see this https://islamqa.info/en/10995

Answer (score 2):

You listen. And you remain silent even if you can not properly hear.

> So, when the Quran is recited, listen to it, and be silent that you
>   may receive mercy.

Al-A'raf 204

Answer (score 0):

During jama'at if you're not hearing what imam reading just keep in your mind Allah is seeing you. Your eye focus should be on your foot.
We'll not get any bad thoughts if we keep in mind just one thing "Allah is seeing me." 
May Allah peace upon us.

Answer (score 0):

In all cases, you're obligated to recite Surah Al-Fatiha in Salah. If it was a Salah (fajr, jumuah, first 2 rakahs of maghrib, first 2 rakahs of Isha) where an imam recites loudly, then also recite Al-Fatiha, but don't recite a Surah after it.

> Abu Huraira reported:
>
> The Apostle of Allah (ﷺ) said: If anyone observes prayer in which he does not recite Umm al-Qur'an, It is deficient [he said this three times] and not complete. It was said to Abu Huraira: At times we are behind the Imam. He said: Recite it inwardly, for he had heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) declare that Allah the Exalted had said: I have divided the prayer into two halves between Me and My servant, and My servant will receive what he asks. When the servant says: Praise be to Allah, the Lord of the universe, Allah the Most High says: My servant has praised Me. And when he (the servant) says: The Most Compassionate, the Merciful, Allah the Most High says: My servant has lauded Me. And when he (the servant) says: Master of the Day of judg- ment, He remarks: My servant has glorified Me. and sometimes He would say: My servant entrusted (his affairs) to Me. And when he (the worshipper) says: Thee do we worship and of Thee do we ask help, He (Allah) says: This is between Me and My servant, and My servant will receive what he asks for. Then, when he (the worshipper) says: Guide us to the straight path, the path of those to whom Thou hast been Gracious not of those who have incurred Thy displeasure, nor of those who have gone astray, He (Allah) says: This is for My servant, and My servant will receive what he asks for. Sufyan said: 'Ala b. 'Abd al-Rahman b. Ya'qub narrated it to me when I went to him and he was confined to his home on account of illness, and I asked him about it.
>
> [Saheeh Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/4/41)